# How can I modify this function to get the nearest crisp value?

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to figure out how to modify this membership function to find the nearest crisp value. This is just part of the code I am working on and I just want some advice on what I could do to find the nearest crisp value.

```
def membership(inputValue, fuzzySet):
    for p in fuzzySet:
        fuzzyValue, crisp = p
        if crisp == inputValue:
            return fuzzyValue

bottle = {(0.0,0.2), (0.5,0.5), (1.0,1.0), (0.5,1.5), (0.0,2.0)}
```

What the input should look like:

```
>>> membership(2.0,bottle) 
0.0 
>>> membership(0.712321345,bottle) 
0.5
```

Comment: If your goal is to get the nearest crisp value, finding the smallest difference is the correct way instead of an equality check.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom function as the key to the minimum that you are searching for.

```
bottle = {(0.0,0.2), (0.5,0.5), (1.0,1.0), (0.5,1.5), (0.0,2.0)}

def membership(inputValue, fuzzySet):
    p = min(fuzzySet, key = lambda x: abs(x[1]-inputValue))
    return p[0]

print(membership(0.712321345, bottle))
```

output:

```
0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can get your crisp values using

```py
crisps=[v[1] for v in bottle]
```

You can then get the diff between the crisp values and the input using a list comprehension or using a `np.array`.

```py
diff = [abs(crisp - inputValue) for crisp in crisps]
```

Now, you can find the index of the min value using `np.argmin`.

```py
min_ind = np.argmin(diff)
```

Finally, you can convert fuzzySet to a list so that you can index it and use `min_ind` to index your original set to get the fuzzyValue.
Try this full runnable example!

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np


def membership(inputValue, fuzzySet):
    crisps = [v[1] for v in fuzzySet]
    diff = [abs(v-inputValue) for v in crisps]
    min_ind = np.argmin(diff)
    fuzzyList = list(fuzzySet)
    fuzzyValue = fuzzyList[min_ind][0]
    return fuzzyValue

bottle = {(0.0, 0.2), (0.5, 0.5), (1.0, 1.0), (0.5, 1.5), (0.0, 2.0)}
print(membership(2.0, bottle))
print(membership(0.712321345, bottle))
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```